# Check if a contact number exists or not in contacts list using CNContacts in iOS

Tags: ios, cncontact

I'm implementing a logic to check whether a contact exists or not in the contacts list and based upon this result I'm inserting the contact. My progress so far:

```
__block NSString *strPhoneNumber = @"1093874652";

if ([CNContactStore class]) {
    CNContactStore *addressBook = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    NSArray *keysToFetch =@[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{


    NSError *error = nil;
    CNContactFetchRequest *fetchRequest =[[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keysToFetch];

    __block BOOL isExists = NO;

    [addressBook enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error usingBlock:^(CNContact * _Nonnull contact, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    NSArray *phoneNumbers =[[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"];


    if ([phoneNumbers containsObject:strPhoneNumber]) {
        isExists = YES;
        *stop = YES;
    }
    else
        isExists = NO;

    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if (isExists == NO) {
     //This is the method for saving the contacts. I'm not implementing here.                    
     [self saveContactWithName:@"John Doe" withContactEmail:@"johndoe@abc.com@" withContactPhone:str];                                 
    }

    });
  });
}
```

Now, the problem is after enumerating, the code under **if (isExists == NO)** fires several times and saving the contact multiple times.How do I stop it? My only need is if the contact exits then don't save it otherwise save it only one time. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why the second `dispatch_async()`?  Why not just store it instead of setting `isExists`?

Comment: from your code `if ([phoneNumbers containsObject:strPhoneNumber])` will be false always, since `strPhoneNumber` instance is not present in `phoneNumbers` elements. You need to check string equality with predicate or something there.

Comment: @Droppy: You are right there no need of second `dispatch_async()`.  I am going to drop it.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr : strPhoneNumber is mentioned at the top.

Answer (score 1):

replace the below part in your code,

```
NSArray *phoneNumbers = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == [c] %@", strPhoneNumber];
NSArray *filtered = [phoneNumbers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if ([filtered count] > 0) {
    isExists = YES;
    *stop = YES;
}
else
    isExists = NO;

}];
```

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Comment: i think `like[c]` can be replaced with `== [c]`, updating the answer